# android service won't stop

Tags: android, service

I am implementing a service named `Clipboard.class` that will pop up an intent when user copy/cut something. I run and stop the service from `MainActivity.java` when button is clicked.

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void runService()
{
    Intent service = new Intent(this, Clipboard.class);
    run = Clipboard.running == 1 ? true:false;
    if(!run)
    {
        startService(service);
        btn.setText("Tap to stop");
    }
    else
    {
        stopService(service);
        btn.setText("Tap to run");
    }
}
```

and this is my service `Clipboard.class`

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    running = 1;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mCM = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    mCM.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            String newClip = mCM.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newClip.toString(),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Clipboard.this, ShareTo.class);
            dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(dialogIntent);
        }
    });
    return mStartMode;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    running = 0;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Everything works fine, only the service will not stop when I click on stop button, why? I can tell that service isn't stop because after I stop the service, when I copy something the intent will still pop up.

Comment: You're not removing the primary clip change listener.  This is actually a memory leak.

Comment: @DeeV I try to set it to null in `onDestroy()`, but I got `NullPointerException`

Comment: Save a reference to the Listener that you put in with `addPrimaryClipChangeListener`, then remove it with `removePrimaryClipChangedListener(ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener)`

Answer (score 0):

From the google document [Android Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() or stopSelf() is called.

so use like this

```
Intent service = new Intent(this, Clipboard.class);
run = Clipboard.running == 1 ? true:false;
if(!run)
{
    startService(service);
    btn.setText("Tap to stop");
}
else
{
    context.stopService(service);
    btn.setText("Tap to run");
}
```